# Regexp: Remove no alnum chars from a string

Tags: php, regex

how could I remove all characters from a string that aren't `a-z`/`A-Z` and `0-9` and `_` with PHP?
I tried that but it has no effect, it returns the same string back:

```
preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '', 'Testdo123_-:=)§%&');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`preg_` prefixed functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) require [PCRE styled regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) that use [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to separate the regular expression from [optional flags/modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

But you forgot delimiters. Or, to be precise: PHP takes the `[` and `]` as delimiters, leaving just `^a-zA-Z0-9_` as your actual regular expression.

So try this (using `/` as delimiters):

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', 'Testdo123_-:=)§%&')
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're forgetting delimiters:

```
preg_replace('/\W+/', '', 'Testdo123_-:=)§%&');
```

`\W` stands for `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: `\W` means all characters that are **not** word characters (maybe you should add an explanation).

Comment: @Tim: he doesn't use delimiters, I'd guess

Comment: Note that `\w` and its complement `\W` depend on the locale that is used.